# Is there a term for a hobby that requires engagement?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a term for a hobby that requires you to engage with it, whether physically or mentally? Playing an instrument, going to the gym, creating something by hand, writing, or tending to plants would all be examples of this; watching a TV series or scrolling on social media would not. The closest I could come up with is "active hobby" but Googling that phrase just returns results about physically active hobbies.

Comment: Does anyone describe watching a TV series or scrolling on social media as a hobby?

Comment: What @KillingTime said. At first I thought "watching a TV series" is the archetypal [***vegging out***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/veg-out) activity. By comparison, "scrolling on social media" (finger swipe *or* mousewheel roll) seemed like vigorous activity. Then I realised even couch potatoes gotta work those remotes! It's all go!

Comment: Do you consider reading to be active? I think people often list that as a hobby.

Comment: In general, I think most hobbies are the active kind. The more general term would be "leisure activities", this includes watching TV.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hysterical: By comparison, scrolling on social media seemed vigorous.

Comment: Watching a TV series can require you to engage mentally. What about other less-active hobbies like birdwatching or stamp collecting or record collecting (on eBay) or maintaining a website or coarse fishing (the sort where you just sit there all day waiting for a bite) or going on coach tours to sites of historical interest or learning about historical topics in other ways or memorizing lists of sports winners or cue sports?

Comment: All activities require some level of engagement.

Comment: To move the conversation away from passive entertainment, stamp collecting is considered a hobby. For clarity, would stamp collecting match the definition of active or passive?

Comment: @jimm101 philately is active. Collectable stamps don't just turn up at the door unless you have a wide network of pen pals, which in itself would be quite an activity to maintain.

Comment: I should think that any activity that could reasonably be called a _hobby_ would qualify as "requiring engagement". Even if the primary activity is something passive like watching TV or movies, it doesn't actually become a hobby until you _are_ 'engaging' with it, e.g., becoming a 'Trekkie' in watching _Star Trek_ involves paying close attention and later analysing what happens, how it relates (or fails to relate) with other instances, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not believe there is an established canonical term here. You would have to construct a phrase to communicate the concept, and "hobby requiring engagement" does the job as well as any other, I'd expect.

Depending on your context, you may be able to co-opt "activity" to fit your needs, though in the general understanding, TV-watching still constitutes an activity. You may also be able to use "active hobby" in contrast to "passive hobby", though I wouldn't expect someone to automatically understand exactly what the distinction is or where you draw the line.

*Side note: I think commentary on engagement being a spectrum is misdirected. All people have hair (ignoring medical conditions like atrichia), but we still have a word and concept for being "hairy". We can reasonably assume OP wants a term for "a hobby that requires you to [significantly/notably/meaningfully/pick-your-own-vague-qualifier] engage with it", and the ambiguous nature of the concept does not prevent us from conceiving it, communicating it, or naming it.*